# Adding system param and Application at context Issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat6, jasypt

FIRST PART : I was asked to add `-DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PW = pw`  in my startup command because of the properties file to store the db password encrypted instead of plaintext? :S So I added it in JAVA_OPTS. An alternative-> Added the parameter in Catalina.sh. Please let me know if I am wrong here!!! Also provide me the answer with steps as in what to do!!!

SECOND PART: I deployed a war file in webapps(aapbase) folder. Tried to start it through TomcatManager, but it give's me this error : `application at context path could not be started` ...

Does any one have some sort of idea as to what to do here??? 
FYI: using tomcat 6...
I get this error when I run it in Tomcat 6.

ERROR :

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.SimplePBEConfig.getPasswordCharArray(SimplePBEConfig.java:434)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.resolveConfigurationPassword(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:740)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:590)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:570)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:697)
    at org.jasypt.properties.PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.java:72)
    at org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.convertPropertyValue(EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertProperty(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertProperties(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:668)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:643)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:437)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Comment: Re: part 2 - going to need a lot more info here.. post the full exception and we can start there

Comment: Well thats the thing!!! Ok here you go with the exception!

Comment: So what do you think????

Comment: I don't know what the `-D` option does for you but it looks like the [EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/apidocs/org/jasypt/spring/properties/EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) expects encryped properties to be specified like this: `my.value=ENC(!"DGAS24FaIO$)`

Comment: yes the password is encrypted over here. thats what I wrote in the First part... I need to put this -D on startup command... To use the war file. And I did... but still it doesn't work!! :( :'(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a password set in a JVM system property (with -D), you should be using an EnvironmentPBEConfig or EnvironmentStringPBEConfig configuration object instead of the SimplePBEConfig object you seem to be using.

That EnvironmentPBEConfig object will allow you to set the name of the JVM system property that holds the encryption password (setPasswordSysPropertyName("APP_ENCRYPTION_PW")) and therefore make jasypt correctly read and use this password.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is quite old, I faced the same NPE while setting up jasypt 1.9.2 for mule. Make sure you have 'passwordSysPropertyName' property of 'org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig' configured. It should possibly resolve the issue.

```
<spring:bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration"
    class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
    <spring:property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
    <spring:property name="passwordSysPropertyName" value="MULE_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />
</spring:bean>
```